# Как подружить location.search со скриптами для localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Три js скрипта сохраненяют, также выводят значения `input` и `textarea` через `localStorage` при повторном заходе на страницу.

```
        // input text, textarea
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('localstoragesave');
        function checkValidity() {};
        for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
         (function(element) {
           var id = element.getAttribute('id');
           element.value = localStorage.getItem(id);
           element.oninput = function() {
             localStorage.setItem(id, element.value);
             checkValidity();
           };
         })(elements[i]);
        }


        // checkbox
        document.getElementById('8').onclick = function() {
          if(document.getElementById('8').checked) {
            localStorage.setItem('8', "true");
          } else {
            localStorage.setItem('8', "false");
          }
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem('8') == "true") {
          document.getElementById("8").setAttribute('checked','checked');
        }

        document.getElementById('19').onclick = function() {
          if(document.getElementById('19').checked) {
            localStorage.setItem('19', "true");
          } else {
            localStorage.setItem('19', "false");
          }
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem('19') == "true") {
          document.getElementById("19").setAttribute('checked','checked');
        }


        // radio
        var raz = document.getElementsByName('napechataj');
        for (var i = 0; i < raz.length; i++) {
          raz[i].onclick = function() {
            localStorage.setItem('napechatajRaz', this.value);
          }
        }
        if(localStorage.getItem('napechatajRaz')) {
          var napechatajRaz = localStorage.getItem('napechatajRaz');
          document.querySelector('input[name="napechataj"][value="' + napechatajRaz + '"]').setAttribute('checked','checked');
        }
        
        var raz = document.getElementsByName('skazhy');
        for (var i = 0; i < raz.length; i++) {
          raz[i].onclick = function() {
            localStorage.setItem('skazhyRaz', this.value);
          }
        }
        if(localStorage.getItem('skazhyRaz')) {
          var skazhyRaz = localStorage.getItem('skazhyRaz');
          document.querySelector('input[name="skazhy"][value="' + skazhyRaz + '"]').setAttribute('checked','checked');
        }
```

Подскажите решение как сделать чтобы скрипт на странице `page.php?s=1` сохранял одни данные для `input` и `textarea`, а на `page.php?s=2` другие.

Параметр `s=1` взят для примера. Имею ввиду, что в адресе после знака `?` могут быть какие угодно параметры, скрипты должны обрабатывать их как разные страницы.

Мне кажется что можно сделать через `document.location.search`, но не умею писать скрипты.

Comment: GET параметры для каждой страницы уникальны? Можно ли их расценивать как ключи как ключи?

Comment: @SwaD если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то ответ да. Уточню: та часть параметра которая "s" будет присутствовать на разных страницах, та часть которая есть значением ("1") будет на большинстве страниц разная. В принципе, я могу добавить еще один GET параметр, который будет ID страницы. Это упростит задачу?